# Stickyfloat.js to sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidebar, and I want to make it fixed with vertical scroll.
This is my sidebar's `div`:

```
<div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The `div` `.page-sidebar` contains a `ul`, with various `li`, that are the voices of the menu.
The class `.page-sidebar` has the following style:

```
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -100%;
```

I loaded stickyfloat.js, and I initialized it with

```
jQuery('.page-sidebar').stickyfloat({
  duration: 0,
  delay: 0
});
```

But it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Checking out the [stickyfloat.js demo page](https://github.com/yairEO/stickyfloat/blob/master/index.html) I found out that all his menus are first initialized with `position: absolute;`

```
.ad{ position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px; width:240px; height:100px; background:#8B0000; color:#FFF; font-size:2em; text-align:center; line-height:100px; }
.menu{ position:absolute; left:10px; padding:15px; width:210px; background:green; color:#FFF; }
```

Comment: Thanks, with `absolute` it works. In my page I also have an header, with `position:fixed; z-index: 9995;` and when I scroll it overlaps partially with the sidebar. How can I avoid this?

Comment: It will be very helpful if I can see a replication

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:fixed;` with `left:0px; top:0px;`

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution, I set `position:absolute;` on the `<div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">`, and then I initialied StickyFloat in this way:

```
    jQuery('.page-sidebar-wrapper').stickyfloat({
      duration: 0,
      delay: 0,
      startOffset: 0
   });
```